# How to pass underscore by concatenating 2 variable names to PHP Database?

Tags: php, database

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $x=$_SESSION['user'];
    ?>

    <script>
        function retrieve_chatter_name(chatter)   {        
            /* how to pass the value of "chatter" to PHP session variable inside a javascript function */     
            $y=$_SESSION['chatter'];    
        }
    </script>

--------------------------------------------------
    /*another Qn: */
    <?php    
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $x_$y ";
        /* how to retrieve an already existing table with tablename "user_chatter" by passing values of user and chatter to a function */    
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);        
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use `$x_$y` inside a string, it thinks `$x_` is the first variable and `$y` is the second variable. See this https://eval.in/122910

You can use brases `{}` to enclose the variable names

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ${x}_${y} ";
```

To pass a value to javascript, you need to echo the variable like below.

```
<script>
        function retrieve_chatter_name()   {        
            /* how to pass the value of "chatter" to PHP session variable inside a javascript function */     
            var chatter = '<? php echo $_SESSION['chatter'];?>';
            return chatter;
        }
</script>
```

Also noticed that you have not assigned `$y` inside php. You need to do this inside php block.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $x=$_SESSION['user'];
    $y=$_SESSION['chatter']; 
?>
```

Comment: I think you mean `{$x}_{$y}`.

Comment: Thanks and i also need another help..the first part of my Qn.
How to store a javascript variable inside a PHP session variable.

Comment: @SajithNair : Thank you that is working fine.. i just checked it.
can you help me more in solving the first section ?

Comment: @pikachu0 `{$x}_{$y}` and `${x}_${y}`, both will work

Comment: I have updated my answer, what is not working in first section?

Comment: You want to pass chatter value to php or javascript?

Comment: Sorry..you got it wrong way... "retrieve_chatter_name(chatter)" a javascript function... and chatter is a JS variable.. i want to load the value of chatter variable to PHP session variable.."$_SESSION['chatter']. Got it ?

Comment: I think you need to use ajax for that

Comment: Help Please.. Just to manage this scenerio. i am so badly in need of it. Thanks in advance and Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $table = $x."_".$y;
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
```

Try the above